# Python: update global from thread

Tags: python

There are several similar questions, I have applied the method suggested but it does not appear to work.

I am trying to update a global variable DYNOK in the master from a thread:

## Master

```
import time
import thr

global DYNOK
DYNOK = False
th = thr.thr()
th.start()
time.sleep(1)
print(DYNOK)
```

## Thread

```
from threading import Thread 

class thr(Thread):
  def __init__(self):
    Thread.__init__(self)

  def run(self):
    global DYNOK
    DYNOK = True
    print(DYNOK)
```

What I am expecting is for the master to print True, however it appears that the global DYNOK does not get updated.

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative solution, suggested by the OP, is to use a callback function for the communication. Along these lines:

Master: (partial, see OP to fill gaps)

```
DYNOK = False

def setDYNOK(val):
    global DYNOK
    DYNOK = val
    print "New value for DYNOK set:", DYNOK


th = thr.thr(setDYNOK) #pass the callback func to the thread initialiser
...
```

Thread:

```
from threading import Thread 

class thr(Thread):
    def __init__(self, callback):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.callback = callback

    def run(self):
        self.callback(True) #calls Master's setDYNOK to communicate new value
```

Answer (score 2):

As your Master and Thread are separate files (based on the imports), they are then also separate modules with their own namespaces.

So to make what you have work you'd need to import master from thr and then use master.DYNOK there. That however doesn't work as it would create a circular dependency as master also imports thr.

If you want to keep the modules separate but share state you can create a third file i.e. module, e.g. state.py, and then say DYNOK = False there. And import state & use state.DYNOK in master and thr. The global keyword is not necessary anywhere when you do this.

Comment: Understood, but it seems a bit strange to create a module just to hold a single variable. Is it possible to use a callback from the thread to the master or does this have the same problem ?

Comment: No problem there: when you create the thread from master you can pass a callback function as a parameter and then just keep a ref to it in the thread and call it when you will. No imports are needed for that so no problem with circular deps. Good idea I'd say :)

Comment: Can you point me in the direction of how I would pass a callback function to the thread ?

Comment: ok i'll do it in another answer as the comments can't be formatted